# Couldn't understand crash log partial apply forwarder for closure #1

Tags: ios, swift, crash-reports

I am getting following crash with Hockey App

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   App                         0x000000010302e7f8 partial apply forwarder for closure #1 (__C.UIImage?, [Swift.AnyHashable : Any]?) -> () in static App.ImageLoader.image(from: __C.PHAsset, size: __C_Synthesized.CGSize, success: (__C.UIImage) -> ()) -> () (PhotoLibraryImageLoader.swift:28)
1   App                         0x000000010302d958 reabstraction thunk helper from @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@owned __C.UIImage?, @owned [Swift.AnyHashable : Any]?) -> () to @escaping @callee_unowned @convention(block) (@unowned __C.UIImage?, @unowned __C.NSDictionary?) -> () (PhotoLibraryImageLoader.swift:0)
2   Photos                               0x00000001917c89cc __84-[PHImageManager requestImageForAsset:targetSize:contentMode:options:resultHandler:]_block_invoke.1505 + 816
```

In  PhotoLibraryImageLoader.swift

```
static func image(from assest:PHAsset,size:CGSize,success:@escaping (_ image:UIImage) -> Void) {
        let option = PHImageRequestOptions()
        option.isSynchronous = false
        option.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
        PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: assest, targetSize: size, contentMode: .aspectFill, options: option) { (image, attributes) in
            success(image!) // Crash line  PhotoLibraryImageLoader.swift:28
        }
 }
```

If there is issue for optional (`image!`) crash log should be different (something like unexpectedly found nil..)

Here What does mean **partial apply forwarder for closure**

Anyone can help me to get idea about it ?

Comment: hi have you got any solution for this?

Comment: @Kakumanusivakrishna Yes         option.isSynchronous = false
        option.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true added as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image which is not available cause the crash (they need to download from server)

to do this  add one line to option

```
    option.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
```

Hope it is helpful to someone

Answer (score 0):

I believe the crash is due to strong reference. Are you calling any released object in the completion block?

Use the following check in the completion handler if required.

```
if let wSelf = self {
    println("i have image now")
    // do what you want with the image/self
}
```

Comment: But it is static function  so weak not allowed because `public final class ImageLoader : NSObject`